# How to append data table in html table using json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I need to show all table fixture layout in html table using ajax method but it doesn't working i dont know the problem please some one help me friends and my code. . .

Controller JsonResult

```
 public JsonResult FixturesVal(string TournamentName, string GroupName, string MatchDate, string MatchType, string GroundName, string MatchName, string TeamA, string TeamB, string Schedule)
    {
        string League = "";
        DateTime MatchPlayedOn = DateTime.ParseExact(MatchDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        if (MatchType == "League")
        {
            League = objdetails.LeagueValidation(TournamentName, GroupName, MatchPlayedOn, MatchType, GroundName, TeamA, TeamB,Schedule);
        }

        if (League == "OK")
        {
            objdetails.AddFixture(TournamentName, GroupName, MatchType, MatchPlayedOn, Schedule, GroundName, MatchName, TeamA, TeamB,"New Tournament");
            League = objdetails.Save();
        }

        //var FixtureLayout = objdetails.TeamsForFixtures(TournamentName);
        int value = objdetails.Number(TournamentName, GroupName);
        var data = new { League, value };            
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My Jquery

```
    $.post("/Fixtures/FixturesVal", { TournamentName: TournamentName, GroupName: GroupName, MatchDate: date, MatchType: MatchType, GroundName: ground, MatchName: $('#MatchCount').val(), TeamA: TeamA, TeamB: TeamB, Schedule: sche }, function (result) {
      $('#MatchCount').val("M" + result.value);
              $.each(result.FixtureLayout, function (i, value) {
                   tbody += '<tr><td>' + value.GroupName + '</td><td>' + value.MatchDate + '</td></tr>';
               });
       alert(tbody);
},"json");
```

This functions are not working

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Also post your complete Action method?

Comment: No wait i put my full post

Comment: What do you mean by not working? you get any result from alert(tbody)  or not.?

Comment: no didnot get any alert message

Answer (score 0):

*Regarding general error detection in javascript :*

Fire up your browser console and check for errors.

You may want to add a `.fail` callback to your `$.post()` call :

```
$.post(...).fail(function(){  console.log('error', arguments);  });
```

to see if your request fails.

---

*Regarding your specific problem :*

Try specifying the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) parameter in your [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) call :

```
$.post(url, {...}, function(result){...}, "json")
```